# Minimizing MSE of a uniform distribution question

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

I always have trouble with Minimizing MSE problems where MSE stands for the Mean Squared Error.  Here is one such problem that gives me trouble:

> A random sample of size n is taken from a uniform distribution, $U(0,\theta)$.  Find the value $c$ such that an estimate of $\theta$ of the form $c X_{n:n} $ minimizes the mean squared error.

$X_{n:n}$ is the order statistic, for example $X_{1:n}$ is the first order statistic and $X_{n:n}$ is the largest order statistic.

I know to minimize the mean square error you have to set its derivative to $0$ and its general form is $MSE(T) = Var(T) + [b(T)]^2$, where $b(T)$ is the bias function, but how would you find the MSE in this case?

Comment: Start by finding the distribution of the maximum $T=X_{n:n}.$ The constant $c$ will depend on $n.$ What is the dist'n of the max of a random sample from UNIF(0,1)?

Comment: Doesn't it follow $Beta(n,1)$?

Comment: It only follows $\textrm{Beta}(n,1)$ if the distribution is a standard uniform. Yours is $\textrm{Unif}(0,\theta)$.